# How to create profile js file for Dojo build 1.10

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I am new in Dojo & got a enhancement project, which needs to be upgraded from Dojo 1.4 to Dojo 1.10 version. There is one package inside which all .js, .css(themes) & .html(templates) files resides.

I have gone through the official document of Dojo 1.10 (**dojotoolkit.org**) and have made changes in .js & .html file as per the Dojo 1.10 release.

I have doubts in Build part. I am referring to official Dojo 1.10 build release documentation (**dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/index.html**)

Suppose My custom package/folder/directory name is "app" inside which .js files are there including two sub folders "themes" (for .css files) & "templates" (for .html files),

And dojo, dojox, dijit & app are in same hierarchy level inside the project.

Now, I have confusion in "Package Build profile", "Application Build profile" & package.json files.

1. Are "Package Build profile" & "Application Build profile" both mandatory to be created or anyone of these is fine ?
2. Is it mandatory to create package.json file for both of the profile files and in above cases ?
3. What will the position of "Package Build profile" & "Application Build profile" & package.json file in hierarchy.
4. Which one is the correct syntax for "Application Build profile" (https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/index.html) or (https://www.sitepen.com/labs/code/performance/sitepen.profile.js)
5. How the build release path will be defined in Dojo 1.10.
6. What will be the location of Templates & Themes directory when creating build, using the build making utility (CMD utility).

Comment: Same problem here, trying to get a build of Dojo working on Android 6+.